# How to avoid submissions with the same e-mail address?

Tags: webforms, 9

How can I prevent that someone submits a form with the same address in an e-mail field again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the unique box in the Form validation settings.

[image: unique_validation]

Comment: Ah, thank you! The help text is saying "Check that all entered values for this element are unique", so I thought it means that in case that the field allows multiple values, it should only allow unique ones...